# Agreement of past participle of verb after direct object pronouns in 1st/2nd person

Tags: grammar, pronouns, agreement, past-participle, past-tense

I am aware that the past participle of a verb which comes after a direct object pronoun in 3rd person *must* agree in gender and number with the pronoun. Is the same obligatory for 1st/2nd persons pronouns? Which sentences of the following pairs are correct?

(individual of a group with at least one man)

- Ci hanno battuto.
- Ci hanno battuti.

(woman speaking)

- Mi hanno battuto.
- Mi hanno battuta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [article by Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato) both possibilities (that is, agreement and not agreement of past participle with the personal pronoun) are correct:

> 2) accordo del participio d'un verbo composto con avere con l'oggetto anteposto, costituito da un pronome personale o relativo ("ci ha *ingannato*" - "ci ha *ingannati*", "la casa che ho *comprato*" - "la casa che ho *comprata*"); 
>   3) accordo del participio di *essere* o di un verbo copulativo col soggetto o col nome del predicato ovvero col complemento predicativo ("il suo discorso è *stato*, è *risultato* una sorpresa" - "è *stata*, è *risultata* una sorpresa"); 
>   4) accordo del participio d'un verbo pronominale col soggetto o col complemento oggetto, sia esso anteposto o posposto ("la meta che ci siamo *prefissati*" - "che ci siamo *prefissata*". 
>   
>   La possibilità di scelta per i punti 2, 3 e 4 è esistita da sempre in italiano e le restrizioni di tanto in tanto indicate da qualche grammatico sono da considerarsi infondate. Anche in uno scrittore particolarmente sensibile al problema dell'omogeneità linguistica come Alessandro Manzoni si possono cogliere alternative: "le cose che m'hanno *fatto*" (*I Promessi Sposi*, cap. XXXV) - "le ciarle che avrebbe *fatte*" (cap. III), - [gli uomini] "si riunivano in crocchi, senza essersi *dati* l'intesa" (cap. XII) - "altri passeggeri s'eran *fatta* una strada ne' campi" (cap. XI) ecc.»

Your question corresponds to point 2 in this explanation, which affirms that both possibilities ("ci ha *ingannato*" and "ci ha *ingannati*" in the examples of this article) are correct. That is, all the sentences in your question are correct and the choice between them it's up to you.