# È corretto dire "Ci ha veramente soddisfatto" o serve "soddisfatti"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, grammatical-number

È corretto dire "Ci ha veramente soddisfatto"? Oppure, dato il plurale, devo dire "Ci ha veramente soddisfatti?

Anche nel caso di una donna che parla direi che sia "Mi ha veramente soddisfatto/a" vanno bene. A me la forma maschile pare generica, ma non ne sono sicura. Che sia forse solo accettabile nella lingua parlata e informale?

Comment: Non sto dicendo che sia un duplicato, ma hai provato a guardare tra le domande con la tag “agreement”?

Comment: Credo che la risposta a questa domanda risponda anche alla tua; è così? https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/agreement-of-past-participle-of-verb-after-direct-object-pronouns-in-1st-2nd-per